# sha256 digest only works with &*

Tags: rust

When I'm creating a sha256 sum with the `sha256` crate, there is an old deprecated way `digest_bytes` (which works) and the deprecation also suggest to use the new `digest` function. When I use the new function as a drop in replacement, an error appears and the compiler suggest a solution which is very strange but works.

```rust
fn main() {
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read("./Cargo.toml").unwrap();
    let hash: String = sha256::digest_bytes(&bytes); // deprecated but works
    // let hash: String = sha256::digest(&bytes); // does not work
    // let hash: String = sha256::digest(&*bytes); // works, but why
    println!("{}", hash);
}
```

Here the error when I use the `sha256::digest(&bytes);` line

```
  --> src/main.rs:3:31
   |
3  |     let hash = sha256::digest(&bytes);
   |                -------------- ^^^^^^ the trait `Sha256Digest` is not implemented for `&Vec<u8>`
   |                |
   |                required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
note: required by a bound in `sha256::digest`
  --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sha256-1.1.4/src/lib.rs:48:18
   |
48 | pub fn digest<D: Sha256Digest>(input: D) -> String {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `digest`
help: consider dereferencing here
   |
3  |     let hash = sha256::digest(&*bytes);
   |                                +
```

Applying the suggested solution `&*` works then, but I don't understand why this works. Maybe someone can explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Vec` can be *dereferenced* to get a slice. If `bytes` has the type `Vec<u8>`, then `*bytes` has the type `[u8]`, and `&*bytes` has the type `&[u8]`. This behaviour is implemented in the `Deref` implementation for `Vec<_>`.

The `digest_byte()` function is declared like this:

```
pub fn digest_bytes(input: &[u8]) -> String
```

If you call this function as `sha256::digest_bytes(&bytes)`, the compiler sees that you pass in an `&Vec<u8>`, while the function expects an `&[u8]`. According to [Rust's coercion rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), the compiler will apply a *deref coercion* in this case, implicitly converting `&Vec<u8>` to `&[u8]`.

However, the `digest()` function is declared like this:

```
pub fn digest<D: Sha256Digest>(input: D) -> String
```

If you call `digest(&bytes)`, the compiler again sees that you pass in an `&Vec<u8>`, but the compiler does not know what target type you actually want. The declaration just states that you need some type `D` that implements the `Sha256Digest`. There could be many types implementing that trait. The compiler does not try applying arbitrary coercions in an attempt to end up with a type that actually satisfies the trait bound (and doing so would be a really bad idea). So for the generic version of this function, you have to manually dereference `bytes` to a `&[u8]`, which is done using `&*bytes`.

The main difference between the two invocations is that in the first case, the compiler knows that the required type is `&[u8]`, while in the second case, all the compiler knows is that the required type is some `D` that needs to be inferred by the compiler first. You can also tell the compiler what you want `D` to be; `sha256::digest::<&[u8]>(&bytes)` will work as well, since you told the compiler that `&bytes` needs to be converted to `&[u8]`.

Comment: This is a great answer. I would also add that you can call `bytes.deref()` or `bytes.as_slice()` if you do not like reborrowing.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes totally sense.